# I want to allow .xls file to upload in my WordPress, I have tried lot of things but it is still not working I don't know why

Tags: php, wordpress, mime-types

I am getting the following error when trying to upload a xls file.

> Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.

Tried plugin [wp-extra file type](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-extra-file-types) and there is no option to choose an xls file type.

tried pro mime type plugin, there is an option for Xls to allow and I did it too but still not working and getting the same error.

Also tried to add the following code in a function.php

```
function my_myme_types($mime_types){
      // New allowed mime types.
$mime_types['xls'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';

return $mime_types;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'my_myme_types', 1, 1);
```

but still showing the same error.

Also tried

```
function wpse294198_mime_types( $mimes ) {
    $mimes['xls|xlsx'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
    return $mimes;
}
add_filter( 'mime_types', 'wpse294198_mime_types' );
```

the only solution worked is wp-config ALLOW UNFILTERED UPLOADS. but this is risky if we considered the security reason. I just want to allow xls file not any other file format like Php, js extra.

```
 define(‘ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS’, true)
```

the problem I face with the above solution that now anyone can upload any type of file from anywhere if there is upload option for him. So I believe this is not a good thing. I need a better solution to my problem.

Comment: Your `my_myme_types()` has param `$mime_types` but you modify `$mimes`

Comment: @Justinas sorry, I did mistake while typing here but in my code it was correct and still gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Try using that plugin WP Extra File Type again.

- Check "check only file extensions"
- Check "skip wordpress check"

**Add custom file types:**

- description: ms excel
- file extension: .xls
- mime type: application/vnd.ms-excel

after that you need to check the .xls extension from that list and it should work.

Comment: same error. Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.

Comment: Ok. Try using that plugin WP Extra File Type again.

Check "check only file extensions",
Check "skip wordpress check",

`Add custom file types:
- description: ms excel
- file extension: .xls
- mime type: application/vnd.ms-excel`

Comment: yes, it worked out now it is working. so now it will only check file extension not it's mime type right?

Comment: can you edit the answer and solution? So, it will help out others too. also, explain to me why it was not working earlier? I will approve and upvote...

Comment: I was already checking the extension part with in_array function. but the thing was after that the WordPress code check it again and finally it failed to upload because of the security error it shows. with the solution it seems like it do not check MIME tyeps anymore.

Comment: when I check Skip WordPress checks. wp extra file type plugin start showing .xls extension which was no there before to allow it. after checking it, it allows me to upload the file... I do not need to add the new one but I will tried that apprach too and worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Checking "check only file extensions" in the WP Extra File Type plugin worked for me too as per Paul Istrate's answer.
Also to note that other fixes that are popular online and that have a very poor security profile also did not work for me. Some people are advocating editing wp-config.php and adding unrestricted upload code:
*define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);*
which is a very BAD idea.